# Fluent NHibernate missing one to many references

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have abstract class MultipleItems which has list of OrderItem objects:

```
public abstract class MultipleItems
{
    ...
    private IList<OrderItem> _orderItems = new List<OrderItem>();

    public virtual IList<OrderItem> OrderItems {
        get
        {
            return this._orderItems;
        }
        set { }
    }
    ...
}
```

Class Menu inherits class MultipleItems:

```
public class Menu : MultipleItems
{
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }

    public Menu(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }

    public Menu() { }
}
```

I'm mapping it table-per-type:

```
public class MultipleItemsMap : ClassMap<MultipleItems>
{
    public MultipleItemsMap()
    {
        Id(i => i.id);
        Map(i => i.Total);
        Map(i => i.Discount);
        HasMany(i => i.OrderItems).Cascade.All();
    }
}

public class MenuMap : SubclassMap<Menu>
{
    public MenuMap()
    {
        KeyColumn("id");       
        Map(i => i.Name);
    }
}
```

Problem is, when I try to load menus with, for example, this:

```
session.QueryOver<Menu>().Fetch(i => i.OrderItems).Eager.List();
```

List is empty when it shouldn't be... I also checked SQL query and it's all there, but just isn't loading.

EDIT: OrderItem class:

```
public class OrderItemMap : ClassMap<OrderItem>
{
    public OrderItemMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.id);           
        Map(x => x.Total);
        Map(x => x.Qty);
        Map(x => x.ItemName);
        Map(x => x.ItemType);
        References(x => x.Item).Not.LazyLoad();

    }
}
```

Comment: What happens when you make the base class non-abstract?

Comment: Same thing unfortunately...

Comment: Where is your `OrderItem` class map? Can we see that?

Comment: What about the `ClassMap` for it? I'd say your main issue is that the public properties have `protected set`.. meaning only subclasses can set their values (NHibernate can't set them).

Comment: Sorry, it's there now. I'll look into protected set now, but I don't think that's the problem

Comment: Your mappings look fine. I would say its the `protected set`. Make them all just public `get; set;` and see how it goes.

Comment: No, it's still the same. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your mapping for OrderItems doesn't specify that the collection should be mapped to a private field, and the empty set causes the list to not be populated. I would remove the empty setter and change the mapping to:

```
public class MultipleItemsMap : ClassMap<MultipleItems>
{
    public MultipleItemsMap()
    {
        Id(i => i.id);
        Map(i => i.Total);
        Map(i => i.Discount);
        HasMany(i => i.OrderItems).Access.CamelCaseField(Prefix.Underscore)
            .Cascade.All();
    }
}
```